# Complex JPA query with nested JOINs using Criteria API

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Suppose I have a SQL like that:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    A a
LEFT JOIN
    B b
    JOIN C c ON (c.b_id = b.id AND c.whatever > 0)
ON (a.id = b.a_id)
```

Now I start coding using the criteria API:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> criteria = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> a = criteria.from(A.class);
```

Now what?

I can't `Join<A, B> b = a.join("b")` yet.

The `a.join(???)` should be called over something else, that happens to have `b` defined.

That something else is the result of joining together `B` and `C` (plus a custom `ON` clause, stating that only some `C`s - those with `whatever` bigger than zero - are acceptable). That something else still exposes `B` and `C` separately (for further predicate filtering with `where` and/or column projection with `select`).

**UPDATE**

What's the difference between

(1) `A a LEFT JOIN (B b JOIN C c ON (c.b_id = b.id AND c.whatever > 0)) ON (a.id = b.a_id)`; and
(2) `(A a LEFT JOIN B b ON (a.id = b.a_id)) JOIN C c ON (c.b_id = b.id AND c.whatever > 0)`?

*[parenthesis were added for clarity; they are never required]*

The `ON` clause can be understood as "closing" the last "still open" JOIN. The `JOIN` clause (any type) can be understood as "opening" a new JOIN; these JOINs are stacked on "opening" and unstacked on "closing".

In (1), the order is: I-JOIN(B and C), then L-JOIN(A and *that*).
In (2), the order is: L-JOIN(A and B), then I-JOIN(*that* and C).

*[I-JOIN is an INNER JOIN and L-JOIN is a LEFT OUTER JOIN]*

For the sake of simplicity, just take the table C to be empty. So, no matter what JOIN you make, any reference to C (i.e. to its columns) will always be `NULL`.

Now, in (1) there will be one result per row in A. Because I-JOIN(B and C) will always produce no rows (remember, C is empty, so any INNER JOIN is empty too); then L-JOIN(A and empty) will produce A and all columns from B and C will be NULL.

In (2) the result will be totally empty. No matter how many rows L-JOIN(A and B) produces (there will be at least one row per row of A), the final INNER JOIN with empty C entails an empty result (no rows at all).

Comment: (1) How is your query different from `SELECT a.* FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id = b.a_id JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id WHERE c.whatever > 0`? (2) Remember that with JPA, you're querying objects, not tables. There's no such thing as an 'intermediate join result'

Comment: @crizzis I've changed the `JOIN` between B and C to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I'll update the post to explain the difference inline.

Comment: @crizzis the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should be actually between A and the rest. It is all explained in the post now.

Comment: Yes, we're querying objects, not tables. Nevertheless each object maps to a row, each class maps to a table. The problem presented is resolved in SQL (with correct nesting of JOINs). I wonder if there is a similar solution in criteria API, because the problem is not fundamentally changed when switching objects for rows, classes for tables.

Comment: OK, so unless I'm missing something, you want `SELECT a.* FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.a_id LEFT JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id WHERE b.id IS NULL OR c.whatever > 0`. That you should be able to express using the Criteria API

Comment: @crizzis They would not be the same. Suppose the case where a row in A has a matching row in B (so, for this one row A LEFT JOIN B will produce all columns for A and B, with non-NULL B.id). Now suppose an empty C, so your last LEFT JOIN will leave all rows from A JOIN B untouched, plus a bunch of C columns all NULL. Now your WHERE clause will ditch that previously stated row, because neither `c.whatever > 0` (all columns of C are NULL), nor `b.id IS NULL` (there is a row in B matching that one in A).

Comment: See this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f3aa1